# Division operator overloading parameters have same values

Tags: python, matrix, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication

I'm having some problems with operator overloading. If you could check please.

The code:

```
import math

class Mat4:
    cells = [   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0] ]

    @staticmethod
    def DET2(a, b, c, d):
        return a * d - b * c

    @staticmethod
    def DET3(a,b,c, d,e,f, g,h,i):
        return a * Mat4.DET2(e,f,h,i) - b * Mat4.DET2(d,f,g,i) + c * Mat4.DET2(d,e,g,h)

    @staticmethod
    def DET4(a,b,c,d, e,f,g,h, i,j,k,l, m,n,o,p):
        return ( a * Mat4.DET3(f,g,h,j,k,l,n,o,p) - b * Mat4.DET3(e,g,h,i,k,l,m,o,p) + c * Mat4.DET3(e,f,h,i,j,l,m,n,p) - d * Mat4.DET3(e,f,g,i,j,k,m,n,o))

    @staticmethod
    def Scale(factor):
        res = Mat4()
        res.cells = [ [factor,0, 0, 0],
                [0, factor, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, factor, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1] ]
        return res
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Mat4):
            print(self.cells)
            print(other.cells)
            print("h\n")            
            out = Mat4()
            for row_left in range(4):
                for col_right in range(4):
                    out.cells[row_left][col_right] = 0
                    for k in range(4):
                        out.cells[row_left][col_right] += self.cells[row_left][k] * other.cells[k][col_right]
            return out

        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(4):
                    self.cells[i][j] *= other  
            return self

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print(self.cells)
        print(other.GetInversed().cells)
        print("pl\n")
        return self * other.GetInversed()

    @staticmethod
    def Identity():
        return Mat4.Scale(1)

    @staticmethod
    def RotationX(angle):
        sinTheta = math.sin(angle)
        cosTheta = math.cos(angle)
        res = Mat4()
        res.cells = [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, cosTheta, -sinTheta, 0],
                [0, sinTheta, cosTheta, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1] ]
        return res

    def GetInversed(self):
        a = self.cells[0][0]
        b = self.cells[0][1]
        c = self.cells[0][2]
        d = self.cells[0][3]
        e = self.cells[1][0]
        f = self.cells[1][1]
        g = self.cells[1][2]
        h = self.cells[1][3]
        i = self.cells[2][0]
        j = self.cells[2][1]
        k = self.cells[2][2]
        l = self.cells[2][3]
        m = self.cells[3][0]
        n = self.cells[3][1]
        o = self.cells[3][2]
        p = self.cells[3][3]
        min_a = Mat4.DET3(f,g,h,j,k,l,n,o,p)
        min_b = Mat4.DET3(e,g,h,i,k,l,m,o,p)
        min_c = Mat4.DET3(e,f,h,i,j,l,m,n,p)
        min_d = Mat4.DET3(e,f,g,i,j,k,m,n,o)
        det_m = a * min_a - b * min_b + c * min_c - d * min_d

        res = Mat4()
        res.cells[0][0] = min_a
        res.cells[1][0] = -min_b
        res.cells[2][0] = min_c
        res.cells[3][0] = -min_d
        res.cells[0][1] = -Mat4.DET3(b,c,d,j,k,l,n,o,p)
        res.cells[1][1] = Mat4.DET3(a,c,d,i,k,l,m,o,p)
        res.cells[2][1] = -Mat4.DET3(a,b,d,i,j,l,m,n,p)
        res.cells[3][1] = Mat4.DET3(a,b,c,i,j,k,m,n,o)
        res.cells[0][2] = Mat4.DET3(b,c,d,f,g,h,n,o,p)
        res.cells[1][2] = -Mat4.DET3(a,c,d,e,g,h,m,o,p)
        res.cells[2][2] = Mat4.DET3(a,b,d,e,f,h,m,n,p)
        res.cells[3][2] = -Mat4.DET3(a,b,c,e,f,g,m,n,o)
        res.cells[0][3] = -Mat4.DET3(b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l)
        res.cells[1][3] = Mat4.DET3(a,c,d,e,g,h,i,k,l)
        res.cells[2][3] = -Mat4.DET3(a,b,d,e,f,h,i,j,l)
        res.cells[3][3] = Mat4.DET3(a,b,c,e,f,g,i,j,k)        
        return res * ( 1.0 / det_m)

def main():
    rotMat = Mat4().RotationX(50)
    scaMat = Mat4().Scale(3)
    mRes =  (rotMat * scaMat) / rotMat

    print(mRes.cells)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result I'm getting:

```
mRes = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -0.068840563856158, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

The result I should get, because rotation gets subtracted and only the scaling has left:

```
mRes = [[3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

The problem is with `__mul__` operator because it's having other and self parameters to store same values, but address is not the same:
[image: debugged code matrix]

For some reasons the first time multiplication happens `mRes =  (rotMat * scaMat)` is okay, but the problems comes when the resulted matrix from the division calls division operator, which also calls multiplication operator.

Comment: You have `cells` as a class attribute, initially shared by all instances of the class.  Some of your methods assign a new `cells` value, making it an instance attribute, but for those that don't - you are changing the shared values, thus effectively changing the already-returned value from any other such method.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry if what I'm saying is stupid, but `cells` is not static variable or in python arrays are static by default?

Comment: Anything assigned in the body of a class is shared by all instances of the class, until such time as you assign a value in a particular instance.  Normally something like that would be assigned in the class's `__init__()` method.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks. I feel so dumb.. Please answer the question and I will mark your answer as the best. Thanks again